# If I have three different text file how do I read them then sort them by average?

Tags: python, file, sorting, text-files, average

I am currently writing a code where you ask maths questions. I have saved the students score along with their name in different folders for 3 different classes. Then I have three different files for each test they have done. I want a code that checks if their name is in each file. Then when it checks if the name is in each file I would like to read all three scores from the persons results. Then sort the three scores by average and print it but for each person who has done the test three times.

Here is my code so far that asks the questions and then saves the names and scores to a file etc.:

```
import random

Name =input("What is your name?")
Class =input("What class are you in? (1/2/3)")
TimesDone = input("How many times have you done the test before(1-3)")

Score = 1
Questions = 1

while Questions < 10:
    Randomnumber1 = (random.randint(1,10))
    Randomnumber2 = (random.randint(1,10))

Operators = ['+','-','*']
Operators1 = random.choice(Operators)

print(Randomnumber1, Operators1, Randomnumber2)

if Operators1 == '+':
    answer = (Randomnumber1 + Randomnumber2)
elif Operators1 == '-':
    answer = (Randomnumber1 - Randomnumber2)
elif Operators1 == '*':
    answer = (Randomnumber1 - Randomnumber2)

UserGuess = int(input("What is the answer to the question?"))

if UserGuess == answer:
    print("Well done",Name,"you got the correct answer!")
    Questions = Questions+1
    Score = Score+1
else:
    print("Wrong answer",Name,"the correct answer is",answer,".")
    Questions = Questions+1

if Questions == 10:
    print("You answered all 10 questions and your final score",Score,".")

if Class == '1':
    if TimesDone == '1':
        myfile = open('namesforclass1test1.txt','a')
        names = (Name)
        myfile.write(repr(names))
        myfile.write('\n')
        myfile.close()

        myfile = open('scoresforclass1test1.txt','a')
        scores = (Score)
        myfile.write(repr(scores))
        myfile.write('\n')
        myfile.close()            
    elif TimesDone == '2':
        myfile = open('namesforclass1test2.txt','a')
        names = (Name)
        myfile.write(repr(names))
        myfile.write('\n')
        myfile.close()

        myfile = open('scoresforclass1test2.txt','a')
        scores = (Score)
        myfile.write(repr(scores))
        myfile.write('\n')
        myfile.close()            
    elif TimesDone == '3':
        myfile = open('namesforclass1test3.txt','a')
        names = (Name)
        myfile.write(repr(names))
        myfile.write('\n')
        myfile.close()

        myfile = open('scoresforclass1test3.txt','a')
        scores = (Score)
        myfile.write(repr(scores))
        myfile.write('\n')
        myfile.close()            
elif Class == '2':
    if TimesDone == '1':
        myfile = open('namesforclass2test1.txt','a')
        names = (Name)
        myfile.write(repr(names))
        myfile.write('\n')
        myfile.close()

        myfile = open('scoresforclass2test1.txt','a')
        scores = (Score)
        myfile.write(repr(scores))
        myfile.write('\n')
        myfile.close()
    elif TimesDone == '2':
        myfile = open('namesforclass2test2.txt','a')
        names = (Name)
        myfile.write(repr(names))
        myfile.write('\n')
        myfile.close()

        myfile = open('scoresforclass2test2.txt','a')
        scores = (Score)
        myfile.write(repr(scores))
        myfile.write('\n')
        myfile.close()
    elif TimesDone == '3':
        myfile = open('namesforclass2test3.txt','a')
        names = (Name)
        myfile.write(repr(names))
        myfile.write('\n')
        myfile.close()

        myfile = open('scoresforclass2test3.txt','a')
        scores = (Score)
        myfile.write(repr(scores))
        myfile.write('\n')
        myfile.close()
elif Class == '3':
    if TimesDone == '1':
        myfile = open('namesforclass3test1.txt','a')
        names = (Name)
        myfile.write(repr(names))
        myfile.write('\n')
        myfile.close()

        myfile = open('scoresforclass3test1.txt','a')
        scores = (Score)
        myfile.write(repr(scores))
        myfile.write('\n')
        myfile.close()

    elif TimesDone == '2':
        myfile = open('namesforclass3test2.txt','a')
        names = (Name)
        myfile.write(repr(names))
        myfile.write('\n')
        myfile.close()

        myfile = open('scoresforclass3test2.txt','a')
        scores = (Score)
        myfile.write(repr(scores))
        myfile.write('\n')
        myfile.close()
    elif TimesDone == '3':
        myfile = open('namesforclass3test3.txt','a')
        names = (Name)
        myfile.write(repr(names))
        myfile.write('\n')
        myfile.close()

        myfile = open('scoresforclass3test3.txt','a')
        scores = (Score)
        myfile.write(repr(scores))
        myfile.write('\n')
        myfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Updated the answer, after understanding what user was trying to do.

The first issue I have with this code is that it is very redundant. Python follows DRY (Do not Repeat Yourself) approach. Take the redundant code and create a function out of it and call the function multiple times with different parameters. For example:

```
def write_data_to_file(filename, data):
    myfile = open(filename,'a')
    myfile.write(repr(data))
    myfile.write('\n')
    myfile.close()
```

Next, Here are the changes I would make to the data structure you are using to solve the issue.Using a dictionary of lists would help us. For example:

```
# Instead/ Before storing the data in to text files, store them in dictonaries.
student_score_dict_timesdone_1.update({name: score))
student_score_dict_timesdone_2.update({name: score))
student_score_dict_timesdone_3.update({name: score))

def merged_scores(student_score_dict_timesdone_1,student_score_dict_timesdone_2,student_score_dict_timesdone_3):
    keys_list=[]
    keys_list.append(student_score_dict_timesdone_1.keys())
    keys_list.append(student_score_dict_timesdone_2.keys())
    keys_list.append(student_score_dict_timesdone_3.keys())
    keys_list=list(set(keys_list))
    master_dict = {}
    for key in key_list():
        scores_list=[]
        if key in student_score_dict_timesdone_1:
           scores_list.append(student_score_dict_timesdone_1[key])
        if key in student_score_dict_timesdone_2:
           scores_list.append(student_score_dict_timesdone_2[key])
        if key in student_score_dict_timesdone_3:
           scores_list.append(student_score_dict_timesdone_3[key])
        master_dict.update({name:scores_list})
return master_dict

def average_scores(master_dict):
    average_score_dict={}
    for key in master_dict:
        key_average_score=sum(master[key])/len(master[key]) # This is integer division. Hence only floor values would be saved.
        average_score_dict.update({key:key_average_score})
    return average_score_dict
```

Comment: Sorry about the error I had trouble copying the code. (Forget about the classes function for a minute) I have three .txt files with the scores in and i have three .txt files with the names in. I want a code that can read the all the files and merge the files into one.(for names and score) Then i want the code to be able to find the average from the three scores per every person who has took the test. If this is possible?